# HashMap Object reference confusion

Tags: java, reference, hashmap

Hello I'll go straight into the problem. I know that in HashMaps in java the valueSet stores REFERENCE, that means that if I change that reference the specific value of that key should change too since both refer to the same object.

But I had some problems with my application so I tried to debug it to see how HashMap works practically. So I coded this mini proggram:

```
class Test
{
    private final static HashMap<Integer, String> test = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "String";
        test.put(1, s);
        test.put(2, "2");
        test.put(3, "3");
        s = "1";
        for (Integer i : test.keySet())
            System.out.println("Key: " + i + ", Value: " + test.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Key: 1, Value: String
Key: 2, Value: 2
Key: 3, Value: 3
```

Whats wrong here? I changed the value of String s right before Iterating the HashMap and it still shows the old value. That shows to me that HashMap DOES NOT work with object reference?

Where am I wrong in here?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

Tried with a test Object and the results are even more confusing since it seems like it WORKS for reference but not for Immutable objects as our fellow mate said:

```
class Test 
{
    private final static HashMap<Integer, TestObject> test = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestObject to = new TestObject();
        test.put(1, to);
        test.put(2, new TestObject());
        test.put(3, new TestObject());
        to.setValue(16);
        for (Integer i : test.keySet())
            System.out.println("Key: " + i + ", Value: " + test.get(i).getValue());
    }

    public static class TestObject
    {
        private int value;

        public void setValue(int val)
        {
            value = val;
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

this prints

```
Key: 1, Value: 16
Key: 2, Value: 0
Key: 3, Value: 0
```

Comment: Your first example is based on `pass by value` and the later one is based on `pass by reference` Try to understand the difference between them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Their is nothing wrong with the HashMap. You are mis-understanding the concept of String object.

**String** is immutable.
That means how many time you make changes in string object it will create a new object and provide the reference to variable.

Just test this small Code

```
String s="String";
System.out.println("Old-"+s.hashCode());
s="New String";
System.out.println("New-"+s.hashCode());
```

**Output**

```
Old--1808118735
New-1745736401
```

Here you can see as you made change to String variable it's hascode is changed that means a new object created in String Pool and new reference to the variable.

**I your case**

```
HashMap<Integer, String> test=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
String s = "String";
System.out.println("Adding with -"+s.hashCode());
test.put(1, s);
test.put(2, "2");
test.put(3, "3");
s = "1";
System.out.println("Modified s-"+s.hashCode());
for (Integer i : test.keySet())
    System.out.println("Key: " + i+ ", Value: " + test.get(i)+"  "+test.get(i).hashCode());
}
```

Write it like this and see the magic output.

```
Adding with --1808118735
Modified s-49
Key: 1, Value: String  -1808118735
Key: 2, Value: 2  50
Key: 3, Value: 3  51
```

HashMap still contains the old string reference.

Comment: Thats right, Its what Marwin said. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user3789587: Both Marwin's answer and this one pay too much attention to mutability - they make it sound like the behaviour of the language changes based on mutability. In particular, the phrase "how many time you make changes in string object it will create a new object" is meaningless... you *can't* make changes to a string object, precisely because it's immutable. You can make changes to a string *variable* to make it refer to a different string, but that's a different matter.

Comment: I written this because not even initialization even if your use + (concatenation operator) on string it will create the new object. like s+="h";

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91: Yes, but that's not "making changes to a string object". As soon as you expand it to `s = s + "h"` it's obvious that it's performing concatenation and then assignment. Why make things more confusing than they need to be?

Answer (score 13):

> I changed the value of String s

Yes, you changed the value of `s`. That's *all* you changed. The map still contains the *previous* value of the variable. You haven't changed the meaning of that value.

We can simplify your example to just plain string variables:

```
String x = "hello";
String y = x;
x = "goodbye";
System.out.println(y); // "hello"
```

The assignment (`y = x`) just copies the current value of `x` into `y`. That value is a reference, but it doesn't "know" where it came from - its only relation to the variable `x` is that it happened to be the value of `x` at the time of the assignment. When you later change the value of `x`, that doesn't change the value of `y`.

The exact same thing happens in `Map.put` - the *current value* of the variable is used as the key. Changing the variable's value later doesn't affect the content of the map.

**About mutability**

None of the statements above depend on the mutability of the type in question. For example, you can see the *exact* same behaviour with `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("hello");
StringBuilder y = x;
x = new StringBuilder("goodbye");
System.out.println(y); // "hello"
```

You'll only see a change in behaviour if you change your code more drastically:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("hello");
StringBuilder y = x;
x.append(" world");
System.out.println(y); // "hello world"
```

Compare these statements:

```
// First version
x = new StringBuilder("goodbye");

// Second version
x.append(" world");
```

The first version changes the value of `x`. After the assignment, `x` has a different value: a reference which refers to a different object. It's like moving to a different house: my home address is not the same as it was.

The second version *does not change the value of `x`*. It changes the content of the object that the value of `x` refers to. That's like painting the front door of my house: the address is still the same (it refers to the same house), it's just that some aspect of that house has changed.

Comment: So that means that the HashMap does not hold String s reference but creates a new copy of it?

Comment: @user3789587: It holds the value of the variable `s` at the time of the `put` call. It doesn't hold a reference *to the variable itself*.

Comment: @user3789587 No. It simply means, an assignment is not changing the value in the String object, but barely changing the reference

Comment: No. The `HashMap` holds a reference to the String but all strings in Java are immutable -- which means you cannot modify them once they exist.

Comment: @Marwin the issue is not about being a String or not, its about Object assignment in general.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you use an object of a Class and you use a setter method instead of assignment you could explain to the OP better.

Comment: @user3789587 You're actually correct in your first question. Every time that you assign or pass a reference variable in Java, you create a new copy of the reference. Your variable `s` holds a reference to the string. When you call `put(1,s)`, you're copying that reference onto the stack. The `HashMap` then makes another copy and stores it with the (reference to the) key in the table. When you put a different reference in the `s` variable, the reference in the table is unaffected.

Comment: Not exactly. Of course, if you assign a value, it works the same for any `Object`. But if the object is mutable, you may modify it after it has been inserted into a `Map` (or any other collection).

Comment: @Geek: No, I very deliberately used assignment because it's likely to be simpler to understand. Then move from that to the more complicated `Map` example at the end.

Comment: Can you guys see the edit I made on the main question? It seems that Marwin was right.

Comment: @user3789587: You mustn't take away the idea that immutable types work differently to mutable types... it's just that there are operations on mutable types which don't apply to immutable ones.

Comment: @user3789587: I've edited my answer to include a section about immutability as well.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give u an example: Here the real objects are like any place say **Home** and reference are their address. Now you are making a **list** of addresses it can be HashMap or List of anything.

Assume you have a piece of paper and address of **Home1** written on it. Now you give this paper to you friend to make a list and he copy this address in his list. Now you throw you parer and pick another paper which contain address of **Home2**. Now if you deliver something it will go to **Home2** and if you friend deliver something according to the list it will go to **Home1**.

That's why when you change the value of `s`

```
 s = "1";
```

it change the value of `s` but doesn't change the value of reference inside the list.

****Actually you are not changing the value of the object that pointed by `s` you are telling `s` to point another object.****

Answer (score 0):

As per your code **S** reference pointing to object "**String**". And hashMap key i.e. "**1**" is also pointing to object"String" once  **test.put(1, s);** get executed,now you change **s** pointing object ,means after you change the value of s to 1 ,now s is pointing to object"1" and key "1" of hashmap is still pointing to object "String".